# Several Orbit sliders in one page without breaking the bullets active class

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I have one problem that i cant seem to solve and that is how you can use several sliders in one page without breaking the bullet active class navigation. I have search the issue que and google it without any luck. I have also tried to replicate the code on foundations website(where you use 'featured1' and 'featured2' for id's. But that still breaks the bullets active class its stuck on the first bullet. Now i dont know what the next step is and therefore ask for your help.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what "breaking the bullet active class" looks like? And also post your code?

Comment: Thx for your response:Here is my code https://gist.github.com/wirlen/5254484 and the problem with the active class is i stuck at the first slide. as you can se on this screenshot http://cl.ly/image/0z180u101E0A.

Comment: Did you initialize foundation after you rendered your `li`'s? And have you tried having one orbit and see if that works?

Comment: No i render it all with in the head section, forgot to say that i try to merge orbit in to wordpress but that dosent matter really cause when i just try plain HTML it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i Post my hook that i wrote to make this work in foundation and wordpress.

https://gist.github.com/wirlen/5363881

Hope it works for you aswell if any1 need it :)

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> when i just try plain HTML it's the same problem

You can try the working sample I did for you, given below. Notice that I added a configuration code if you are wanting to change the style of Orbit. Also notice that the initialization of Foundation comes after it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>               <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Foundation Orbit Sample</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />

  <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>   
    <!-- Orbit test -->
    <h1>Orbit Test</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <ul data-orbit id="slider1">
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x350&text=slide 1" /><div class="orbit-caption">Slide 1</div></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x350&text=slide 2" /><div class="orbit-caption">Slide 2</div></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x350&text=slide 3" /><div class="orbit-caption">Slide 3</div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <ul data-orbit id="slider2">
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150&text=slide 1" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150&text=slide 2" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150&text=slide 3" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).foundation('orbit', {
            bullets_container_class: 'your_custom_style_1',
            bullets_active_class: 'your_custom_style_2',
        });

        $(document).foundation();        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey sr for a late answer but i been away. I could not make it work with your code but i guess the problem is Wordpress so i ended up writing an hook into the sliders.